# Javascript onclick increment a number as text

Tags: javascript, onclick, increment

I have a problem with Javascript: I'm trying to increment a number which is a string, so I need to parse it, increment the value, and assign that number to the value in the field. But I don't understand why this code doesn't work properly:

```
<button type="button" onclick="dec()" name="less" style="background-color: orange;border:none;">-</button>
<script>
  function dec() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value, 10);
    x--;
    document.getElementById("num").value = x;
  }
```

While the number is in a div like this:

```
<div id="num" style="display:inline;">0</div>
```

Where is the error?

Comment: a div doesn't have a `value`, use `textContent` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one hand, if you want to increment the value you need to do `x++` instead of `x--`. And after that, I think you will fix it with:

```
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML= x;
```

Because a `div` does not have a `value` property.

Comment: Sorry if I reply late: yes, I made a mistake while I was writing the question. Apart from that, it worked, so thank you!

Comment: @Sharkstroke if that did work for you, please, close it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML
```

instead

Comment: is the exact same answer I gave

Comment: @cor - Sorry. I did not see your answer until page refresed. Should I remove this one?